# how does truffle decide when to update a contract?

Tags: truffle

it has happened to me many times, that after updating a contract and running `truffle migrate` it simply told me `network up to date`

in order to reproduce the behaviour I did the following:

- create a folder metacoin
- run `truffle unbox metacoin`
- edit the `truffle.js` to include a testrpc node as the development network
- run testrpc
- run `truffle migrate`
- edit the file `contracts/Metacoin.sol` and adding a global public variable
- run `truffle migrate` again

I could verify that the address of the contract did not change. I know that I can force a deployment with `--reset` but this is not always a good option.

Comment: Which version of truffle is this. Seems this issue was fixed in 3.4.4 or something about 6 months back

Answer (score 2):

I've had similar issues, even when I change code in the contracts.

Best solution is to `rm -rf ./build` folder, and then run `truffle migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a proper answer. Many times it seems like it doesn't detect a file has changed and it will tell you its up to date.

Sometimes it doesn't say it's up to date but still the compilation and migration seem to be using old versions of the contract and I have to --reset.

Lately I find myself more and more having to also delete the build folder each time to make sure Its actually using the latest files.

Comment: I'm making the same experience. The issue is that you have to copy out the addresses of the deployments and put them back by hand